# Noise after converting 32-bit float PCM to unsigned 8-bit

Tags: audio, pcm, noise

I am trying to convert float PCM audio stream to 8-bit and got acceptable result but it gets some noise. Is it supposed to happen or my function is not sufficient? Converting to signed 16-bit went much better. Is it possible to get 8-bit stream without the noise?

```py
def float32_to_unsigned8(pcm_data_f32):
    pcm_u8 = b''
    for c in chunks(pcm_data_f32, 4):
        f32 = struct.unpack('f', c)[0]
        u8 = int(f32 * 127 + 128)
        if u8 > 255:
            u8 = 255
        if u8 < 0:
            u8 = 0
        pcm_u8 += struct.pack('B', u8)
    return pcm_u8
```

Comment: 8-bit audio inherently has more quantisation noise than 32-bit audio.

Answer (score 2):

The noise is an expected result. An 8-bit signal has a maximum signal-to-noise ratio of 48dB. When reducing the number of bits, it is common practice to apply dither in order to eliminate some of the more objectionable artifacts. Dither will spread the quantization error out over time as broadband noise.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither

Answer (score 1):

As Oli says if your goal is to reduce the information load per sample from 32 bits down to 8 bits, noise is part of the bargain as you are intentionally throwing away information per sample.  If however that is not your intention, and you wish to convert your 32 bit float PCM down to 8 bit where you retain the full information load per sample, you can alternatively output each 32 bit float into four separate 8 bit bytes, instead of one in your above algorithm.  This would not introduce any noise since you will have maintained the full information load.  Let us know if this is your intention and we/I can suggest an alternative algorithm which is basically a series of bit shifting with masking.

Comment: Thanks, Scott! I wanted to reduce the size of the stream and finally ended up with 16-bit since the 8-bit noise was affecting speech recognition.